# Solaris: how to list swap space per process?

Tags: solaris, process, performance-monitoring, swap

On Solaris, how can I find out how much swap space a given process is occupying?
Or even better, how can I list all running processes sorted by swap space usage?

I'm asking this particulary for Solaris. I do not have the `top` command available and neither `prstat` nor `swap` seem to be able to provide information about how much swap space a given process is using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the command:

```
pmap -S <pid>
```

to see all the memory statistics, including swap usage.

With little shell magic you can wrap it in a bash loop:

```
cd /proc
for i in *; do
    SWAP=`pmap -S $i | grep ^total | awk '{ print $3; }'`
    [ "xx$SWAP" != "xx" ] && echo "$SWAP bytes $i"
done | sort -n
```

Output is in bytes, in a format:

```
<number> bytes <pid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if $3 matches the column you want, because it's the "Kbytes" and not "Swap" column.

In the Header it's the 3rd but not in the `grep total` (because of the blank in "total Kb"):

```
Address  Kbytes    Swap Mode Mapped File

total Kb  240576  235028`
```

Answer (score -1):

for i in * ; do pmap -S $i 2> /dev/null | nawk -v PID=$i '$1 == "total" && $4 > 0 {print PID,"=>",$4,$2}' ; done |sort -rn -k 3,3